# Sphinx. ERROR: unknown key name ..

Tags: sphinx, индексация

Начал осваивать Sphinx (установил версию 2.1.6).
При попытке индексации получаю ошибку:

```
using config file '/etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf'...
ERROR: unknown key name 'SELECT' in /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf line 14 col 14.
FATAL: failed to parse config file '/etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf'
```

Вот файл конфигурации:

```
sql_query = \
            SELECT id, occupation, experience, education,
                   branch, typeVacancy, salary, description,
                   city, employer\
            FROM vacancy_view

    sql_attr_uint = salary
    sql_attr_string = city
    sql_attr_string = branch
    sql_attr_string = occupation
    sql_attr_string = experience
    sql_attr_string = education
    sql_attr_string = employer
```

Comment: Пробовал запрос к другой таблице  - результат тот же.

Comment: Непонял. SELECT с новой строки. Т.е. там несколько пробелов от начала строки.

Comment: Ну, вот после первого слеша есть пробел или сразу перевод строки?

Comment: Я понял. Был пробел. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После слеша перед SELECT есть пробел?

UPD: был пробел